# No type arguments expected for class Call

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having an issue.I have project and then i copy paste into an other new project and i'm facing this error

**No type arguments expected for class Call**

In the first project i didn't have any problem...
Here is my interface class which i have the error

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("data/2.5/weather?q=Prague")
    fun getWeatherData(@Query("units") units: String,
                       @Query("appid") appId: String)
            :Call<WeatherData> //here is the error

}
```

and here is my WeatherData class

```
data class WeatherData(
        @SerializedName("coord") val coord: Coord,
        @SerializedName("weather") val weather: List<Weather>,
        @SerializedName("base") val base: String,
        @SerializedName("main") val main: TemperatureData,
        @SerializedName("visibility") val visibility: Int,
        @SerializedName("wind") val wind: Wind,
        @SerializedName("clouds") val clouds: Clouds,
        @SerializedName("dt") val dt: Int,
        @SerializedName("sys") val sys: Sys,
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
        @SerializedName("cod") val cod: Int
)

data class Sys(
        @SerializedName("type") val type: Int,
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("message") val message: Double,
        @SerializedName("country") val country: String,
        @SerializedName("sunrise") val sunrise: Int,
        @SerializedName("sunset") val sunset: Int
)

data class Coord(
        @SerializedName("lon") val lon: Double,
        @SerializedName("lat") val lat: Double
)

data class TemperatureData(
        @SerializedName("temp") val temp: Double,
        @SerializedName("pressure") val pressure: Int,
        @SerializedName("humidity") val humidity: Int,
        @SerializedName("temp_min") val tempMin: Double,
        @SerializedName("temp_max") val tempMax: Double
)

data class Weather(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("main") val main: String,
        @SerializedName("description") val description: String,
        @SerializedName("icon") val icon: String
)

data class Clouds(
        @SerializedName("all") val all: Int
)

data class Wind(
        @SerializedName("speed") val speed: Double,
        @SerializedName("deg") val deg: Int
```

Comment: check if you imported the correct package for `Call`

Comment: i did yeah 
import android.telecom.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

it's exactly the same with the first project.The error though is in <WeatherData>

Comment: Delete `android.telecom.Call`, and import  "the `Call`" from Retrofit

Comment: Damn...Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @Ollaw Put that as an aswer or I will to close this one :)

Comment: @AlexKolydas When responding remember to mention peoples name, that way they get a notification about it.

Comment: @Warpzit ok i'm sorry :D

Comment: @AlexKolydas No problem, just helping you out learning to use the site :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just verify that you've imported the correct package from `Retrofit`.

The correct one is

```
retrofit2.Call
```

not to be confused with, for example

```
android.telecom.Call
```

Comment: Jesus!)))))))))))

Comment: OMG, exactly what my problem is. -_-

Comment: In my case, I had imported `okhttp3.Response`, instead of `retrofit2.Response`.

Comment: Thank you @Ollaw. `retrofit2.Callback` is correct. In my case, i imported `javax.security.auth.callback.Callback` instead of `retrofit2.Callback` .

Answer (score 3):

If you `import` both `Retrofit` and `Okhttp`, make sure the Call class you use is the one from Retrofit:

```
import retrofit2.Call
```

not:

```
import okhttp3.Call
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a look to import section and check whether retrofit2.Call library is imported or not ,sometimes it gets touched with okhttp3.call but you have to use the retrofit one.so make sure the library is imported to the interface/class.